# Why are my class methods unbound?

Tags: python, class-method

Here's a snippet of a python class I am working on.  (Sorry I can't go into too much detail.  My organization gets a little antsy about such things.

```
class my_class:

    @classmethod
    def make_time_string(cls, **kwargs):
    # does some stuff

    @classmethod
    def make_title(cls, **kwargs):
    # does some other stuff

    @classmethod
    def give_local_time(cls, **kwargs):
    # yet more stuff

    @classmethod
    def data_count(cls, **kwargs):
    # you guessed it
```

So far, so good, I should think.  But I am having trouble using this class.  And it turns out that the reason is that the last two methods are unbound:

```
>>> my_class.make_time_string
<bound method classobj.make_time_string of <class __main__.my_class at 0x1cb5d738>>
>>> my_class.make_title
<bound method classobj.make_title of <class __main__.my_class at 0x1cb5d738>>
>>> my_class.give_local_time
<unbound method my_class.give_local_time>
>>> my_class.data_count
<unbound method my_class.data_count>
```

Sorry, again, that I can't be much more forthcoming about the contents.  But can anyone think of a reason why those last two methods should be unbound while the first two are (correctly) bound?

Comment: Post a reproducible minimum example. I guess you are querying from the type in some cases and from an instance in other.

Comment: Works fine here too. What does `dir(my_class)` say?

Comment: OK, I;m new to python classes, so excuse the mistake.  Where my methods are unbound, I have *instance* methods of the same name.  I figured that python would be able to tell the difference between my_class.method() and my_instance.method().  Guess I was wrong.  I haven't actually seen this written anywhere.  Can someone point me to it?  Thanks.

Comment: I guess you are used to a language with function/method overloads...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code, it works for me.

So, you'll need to provide a better example.

My best guess is that you are somehow typo'ing `@classmethod` or are no longer in the class definition or something. Maybe you're overwriting the `classmethod` decorator?

Here's my code:

```
class my_class:
    @classmethod
    def make_time_string(cls, **kwargs):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def make_title(cls, **kwargs):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def give_local_time(cls, **kwargs):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def data_count(cls, **kwargs):
        pass

print my_class.make_time_string
print my_class.make_title
print my_class.give_local_time
print my_class.data_count
```